# Catching cookies with firecookie during page load

Tags: javascript, debugging, cookies, firebug

I need to see what script sets a specific cookie when I load a page. Firecookie seems to work well when the cookie is set after the page loads but is completely useless if the cookie is set before the page loads.

The page I'm debugging doesn't belong to me so I'm kind of limited to doing this in-browser. I really don't want to download all the scripts on the page and dissect them line by line. Is there any way to get Firecookie to break on a script during page load?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get Firecookie to break on a script during page load?
>   If the cookie is set by a Javascript on the page (accessing the document.cookie field) - and so, there is a callstack and line number to show to the user, then Firebug should break (no matter whether it happens during the page load phase or later).

If the cookie is set by the server (cookie is specified in a HTTP header), Firebug can't break (there is no JS script to break on), but you should be able to see a log in the Console panel.

Honza